# Create instance of an unknown class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If you have a known class type string, like for example @"NSString", you would create an instance of that class like so:

```
Class stringClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSString");
NSString* myString = [[stringClass alloc] init];
```

But what if you don't know the type of the class that you receive? I mean, you know it will be a valid one, you just don't know which one ...

Is it still possible to create an instance of that class, not `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling `[[unknownClass alloc] init]` you will always create the actual class. You're only saving the class in an `id` typed variable. But the class itself remains in its type. You could also store a string in an `id` variable, but still use the string methods. E.g.:

```
id string = @"lalalala";
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12]];
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: You don't need to do the `performSelector` dance, and in fact it distracts from your point that `id` types can be messages just as any other type.